# Spring Integration SFTP issue : Accented characters replaced

Tags: java, encoding, ftp, sftp, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Integration to retrieve files from a FTP server (using SFTP).
My problem is that the names of the files on the FTP server contains accented characters ('é', 'à', etc..). The files are found without problems, but once the transfer is complete, the accents are replaced by other characters such as '?'.
I was wondering... is there a config somewhere in Spring Integration that I am missing?

Btw, both the FTP server and the application server are under Linux Ubuntu.

Here's my Spring Integration config :

```
    <beans:bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
        <beans:property name="host" value="${sftp.host}" />
        <beans:property name="port" value="${sftp.port}" />
        <beans:property name="user" value="${sftp.user}" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="${sftp.password}" />
    </beans:bean>

    <sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInboundAdapter"
        channel="sftpReceiveChannel" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        local-directory="file:${files.path}/input"
        remote-directory="${sftp.remote.dir}" auto-create-local-directory="true"
        delete-remote-files="true" filename-regex=".*\.xlsx$">
        <poller fixed-rate="10000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
    </sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm - I just ran a test (mac os x client, Ubuntu 12.04 server).

I wrote a file `é.txt` to the server; the sshd debug log showed

```
close "/home/foo/si.sftp.sample/\303\251.txt" bytes read 3 written 0
```

And I see

```
$ ls ~/si.sftp.sample/ 
é.txt
```

I then fetched the file (no special configuration) and it arrived ok; with the accent.

Comment: Did you ran your test using Spring Integration? Because when I transfer the file using the sftp linux command, everything works fine; the file name remains unchanged. The problem occurs only when the transfer is made using Spring Integration; making me think the problem is Spring related...

Comment: Yes, I used the [sftp sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/sftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/sftp/SftpInboundReceiveSample.java) and changed the filename on [this line](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/sftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/sftp/SftpInboundReceiveSample.java#L49); turned on VERBOSE logging on the server; set breakpoints and checked the filenames on both ends.